# How to uncompress .bz2 file in the background in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to decompress a .bz2 file. I am using the below command.

```
sudo bzip2 -dk latest-all.json.bz2
```

After few min's of decompressing, my putty inactive and it is stops executing. Is there any command to execute in the background even the putty is inactive..?

Thanks

Comment: Don't spam unrelated tags, please. This isn't even a programming question; I don't think it's on-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I am facing this issue in ubuntu server from last one week on words. So, just posted it to get some ideas from our buddies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo nohup bzip2 ... &> /dev/null &
```

`nohup` means "no hangup", it starts the process as a job and gives the command line bacck, so it will stay interative, but the output of the command (echo messages, percetage, whatever) will be shown. To prevent this, end the commad with `&> /dev/null`, it will redirect the standard output and standard error messages to `/dev/null` ("black hole") thus it will be absolutely invisible. The last `&` will send the job to the background, use `jobs` command to check the state of the process (runninng / finished).

Comment: I tried nohup but after sudo. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Does not help - still leaving the terminal might abort